# Can we use epoll() to poll on a descriptor which is using ioctl for data transfer

Tags: c, linux, io, linux-device-driver, epoll

I came to a situation where i have to poll for the events on a file descriptor which is using ioctl command for data transfer(Not using read()). I know epoll() can be used on the file descriptor which uses read() and write() for data transfer. But some drivers uses ioctl commands for data transfers. Can we use epoll() on those type of file descriptors ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the driver. From [LDD3](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-6-sect-3):

> `poll`, `select`, and `epoll` have essentially the same functionality [...]
>
> Support for any of these calls requires support from the device
>   driver. This support (for all three calls) **is provided through the
>   driver's `poll` method**. This method has the following prototype:
>
> ```
> unsigned int (*poll) (struct file *filp, poll_table *wait);
> ```

Put another way, the file descriptor managed by the driver is usable with `select`/`epoll` etc only if the internal `poll` function is implemented.